# How to enable and disable links in php

Tags: php, disable-link

I'm trying to make an if statement to enable and disable user account in href link but I want the link display Disable if the Query return active = 1 and enable if the query return 0.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very unclear what you want exactly. You should rewrite the question more clearly and provide more detail.

At a guess though, is this what you are looking for?

```
 $queryRes = member_enable(); // assuming this returns 1 or 0
 if($queryRes == 0) {
     echo "<a href='enable_member.php?enab=". urlencode($result['member_id'])."' class=\"button-small blue text_upper round\">Enable</a>";
 } else {
     echo "<a href='disable_member.php?deac=" . urlencode($result['member_id'])."' class=\"button-small blue text_upper round\">Deactivate</a>"; 
 }
```

**UPDATE 1** Edited to include code you posted above. Add a return statement to your member_enable function to return number of rows as mentioned in above answer

**UPDATE 2**
Sounds like you simply need to retrieve the relevant fields from the DB on page load, loop through them printing out the info and the link, and then, when a disable/enable link is pressed, load a script which enables/disables the account and then returns the admin to the user management page. By reloading the management page, the links will change to the appropriate text as it will be using the updated database values.

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I'm looking for but how to achieve it

Comment: See Abid's answer. I've made an edit on it  on the if statement as there is a typo. Won't be visible for a few minutes though. I changed the $command variable to $status variable.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers and I tried both your suggestions it didn't work what I'm trying to do is in the if statement call a function to check the active field if = to 1 if it's equal to 1 that's mean you are enabled then display deactivate once you press deactivate link then the active field would be 0 so the if statement would display enable instead, that's where I stuck. I tried several ways it didn't work.

Comment: Just reading over the code you posted above. Things are still unclear I'm afraid. Your MySQL query is selecting a count of the number of all active members. Not sure how this is supposed to tie in with the comment you posted above there. It sounds like you are listing the members in a table perhaps with an enable/disable link beside their name. If this is the case, then why the count of active members query? You could just check the 'active' value and base your if/else off of that.

Comment: Thanks, I tried Abid Hussain code it did work as display deactivate and it does deactivate the user but never show enable again unless I change the condition to == 0 so it does turn the link to enable.

Comment: Well Ren I have the members table in the database with a field active 0 or 1 to enable or disable the member and what I'm trying to achieve now is in the admin panel fetch all the members with enable or disable link next to their name so the admin could disable the account or enable it my functions works fine except display the correct link whick is if the user active field is = 0 display enable other wise display disable. I can't figure out how to do that in php.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add in all the additional detail that you have posted as it is currently hard to keep track of? Sounds like you simply need to retrieve the relevant fields from the DB on page load, loop through them printing out the info and the link, and then, when a disable/enable link is pressed, load a script which enables/disables the account and then returns the admin to the user management page. By reloading the management page, the links will change to the appropriate text as it will be using the updated database values.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
$link = '';
if($status == 1)
{
    $link ='<a href="">Profile</a>';
}

echo $link;
```

**Update**

```
function member_enable(){
    $command = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(member_id) FROM members WHERE active= 1");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($command);

    return $num_rows; 
} 

$status  = member_enable();
if($status >= 1)
{
    echo "<a href='enable_member.php?enab=". urlencode($result['member_id'])."' class=\"button-small blue text_upper round\">Enable</a>";

}else{

    echo "<a href='disable_member.php?deac=" . urlencode($result['member_id'])."' class=\"button-small blue text_upper round\">Deactivate</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks man for the answer but still I didn't get it my code is bellow please help me out.

Comment: <?php
         if(member_enable()){
         echo "<a href='enable_member.php?enab=". 
         urlencode($result['member_id'])."' 
         class=\"button-small blue text_upper round\">Enable</a>";
         }else{
         echo "<a href='disable_member.php?deac=" . 
         urlencode($result['member_id'])."' 
         class=\"button-small blue text_upper round\">Deactivate</a>";
         }
?>

Comment: this is my function function member_enable(){
  $command = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(member_id) FROM members WHERE active= 1");
 }

Comment: Thanks guys I tried Abid Hussain code it did work as display deactivate and it does deactivate the user but never show enable again unless I change the condition to == 0 so it does turn the link to enable.

Comment: try this function function member_enable(){
    $command = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE active= 1");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($command);

    return $num_rows; 
}